# Elusive syntactical error in simple R code

Tags: r, syntax

I'm working on a simple R function as an exercise from a textbook. I have written the function to do the correct action, but I can't understand why mine is throwing a syntax error. I have a solution that works correctly, and both are almost identical so I'm curious as to what is wrong with my code?

This is what the question asks for:

> Write a greeting function that says “good morning,” “good afternoon,”
>   or “good evening,” depending on the time of day. (Hint:
>   use a time argument that defaults to lubridate::now()

My code:

```
 salutations = function(now()){
    hr = hour(now())

    if(4<= hr <= 12){
        print("Good Morning")
    } else if (13 <= hr <= 19){
        print("Good Afternoon")
    } else {
        print("Good Evening")
    }
}
```

Solution Code:

```
 greet <- function(time = lubridate::now()) {
    hr <- lubridate::hour(time)
    # I don't know what to do about times after midnight,
    # are they evening or morning?
    if (hr < 12) {
        print("good morning")
    } else if (hr < 17) {
        print("good afternoon")
    } else {
        print("good evening")
    }
}
```

Some tings to keep note of: I installed the `lubridate`  package so even though I am omitting the `lubridate::` part I feel it should still work. I have the same amount of braces and tabbing as the solution. So what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with the you have an extra '}' at the end of your code. Second (4<= hr <= 12) is not a correct syntax. You can write it as:

```
(hr >= 4 & hr <= 12)
```

Comment: Where is the extra brace? They all match up when I scroll through them. As for the interval, my original idea was to use ```hr %in% [4:12]```

Comment: You have 3 {s and 4 }s.

Comment: Then your only issue is how you format the condition. You have included two conditions into one condition using an invalid syntax. You need to split it and use and (&).

Comment: So if I understand what you're saying, then the second conditon: ```hr %in% 13:19```  is where my issue is?

Comment: (4<= hr <= 12) is wrong syntax, so also (13 <= hr <= 19). hr %in% 04:12 and hr %in% 13:19 are good.

Comment: worked it out, it seems i needed to assign a variable name to my ```now()``` argument in declaring the function. i.e: ```function(time = now())```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the first line you pasted later. Yes, it has to be a variable since you are declaring the function and not calling it. However, note that if your intention is to greet based on current time, you don't need a parameter for this function.

Comment: That's actually how I wanted it to work initially. I'll play with it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`4<= hr <= 12` isn't a valid R syntax.

Probably, what you were trying to do was :

```
library(lubridate)
hr = hour(now())

if(4 <= hr & hr <= 12){
  print("Good Morning")
} else if (13 <= hr & hr <= 19){
  print("Good Afternoon")
} else {
  print("Good Evening")
}
```

Comment: for the interval, my original idea was to use ```hr %in% [4:12]```

Comment: Yes you can use that as well. `if(hr %in% 4:12)`